# insert and update in one query using multiple keys

Tags: mysql

I am trying to find a query that would update if it is a duplicate entry or insert if not. I tried various solutions but nothing works please help me with the same.

My Code is :

```
INSERT INTO yourtable (name, phonecode,value)
VALUES ('bar',91,'300')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name='dgdgf'
```

[image]

Here the issue comes up is my phonecode and value is the key that needs to be checked for the insert or update but making any of them primary would allow duplicate entry and unique would not allow me to a duplicate entry if any one of the row data is same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a multicolumn `UNIQUE` index:

```
ALTER TABLE yourTable
ADD UNIQUE INDEX idx_ph_val (phonecode, value)
```

Now, after the above `ALTER` statement is executed, when you try inserting a duplicate row, the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` will perform just as you desire.

---

### EDIT

SQLFiddle link, as requested in [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33021730/insert-and-update-in-one-query-using-multiple-keys/33021873?noredirect=1#comment53884706_33021873): http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/be84b/1

Comment: i need to make both phonecode and value to match, that is if the insert value matches the phonecode and the value it should update or insert... this is just matching my first value that is the phonecode.. and these values can be duplicated for only one row. I am actually using this for phonecodes and phone numbers, phone numbers can be similar in different countries but in this case the phone code changes or vice versa if phonecode is same but phone numbers differ so in this i need to check both phonecode and phone number and insert if existence is zero...

Comment: @Rebecca I understand. That is what the _multicolumn_ `UNIQUE` index will do.

Comment: ALTER TABLE yourTable
    ADD UNIQUE INDEX idx_ph_val (phonecode, value);


    INSERT INTO yourtable (name, phonecode,value)
    VALUES ('bar',300,'300')
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name='hello';

Is this correct ?

Comment: The `ALTER TABLE` statement needs to be run just once. It'll update your table. Next time onwards, you only have to do `INSERT INTO yourtable (name, phonecode,value) VALUES (something, else, goes-here) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name='wheeee!!';`

Comment: yes i did put the `ALTER TABLE` only once but as seen in the image above in the question, my table gets updated on the id 17 where as it should insert a new row

Comment: `INSERT INTO yourtable (name, phonecode,value)
VALUES ('bar',300,'300')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name='hello';`

this just updated my row id 17

Comment: @Rebecca It is working exactly as expected here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/be84b/1 Maybe you have some other error?

Comment: I think there might be some issues when i created the table, i dropped the table and created it again, works for me now...thanks :) .. It would be helpful if u edit your answer and paste the sqlfiddle url